# HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

firstly I'd like to say that this topic might be related to others, but I can't find a solution for this specific error.
Remembering that this error happens ONLY when I execute my `./mvnw test` within the Dockerfile stage and on CI.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:18.0.2.1_1-jdk-alpine AS test
ENV spring_profiles_active=test
ENV APP=/home/fvapi
WORKDIR $APP
COPY pom.xml mvnw ./
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw test
```

On CI it just clones the repo and execute the same `./mvnw test`.

The error is a loop, and you can see it here: https://pastebin.com/ar5BPXvp

I think the main point here is:

```bash
2022-09-14 04:05:46.254  INFO 131 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
     2022-09-14 04:06:17.298 ERROR 131 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.
     
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

I have already tried looking for anything related to both `HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization`, `loop HikariPool-2 - Starting` and to the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`, but I found nothing relevant.

I also tried these `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_URL_FROM_AWS_RDS/dbname
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

and also

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_URL_FROM_AWS_RDS/dbname?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Can someone please give me a light?

PS.: this error only happens when running using docker and on CI. If I try locally, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

The issue is most likely to be about accessing the database. At initialization time Spring validates the DB with validation query, taking a connection from Hikari Pool. The latter in turn fails to connect the database. You need to double-check the host and the port you are actually trying to connect to and the port exposed by MySQL in CI. From your `application.properties` I see that you don't specify port at all

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_URL_FROM_AWS_RDS/dbname
```

T

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://DATABASE_URL_FROM_AWS_RDS:DATABASE_PORT_FROM_AWS_RDS/dbname
```

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for replying. Indeed, not setting the port is weird but that's how it was configured before and it was working. Now that I have to setup a CICD pipeline, I'm facing this weird issue. I just added the port to the database URL, and apparently it started working when I run the Dockerfile, but it still fails with the exact same error as before on CI... Maybe the CI is limiting access to my AWS database?

Comment: Make sure that MySQL is actually up when you are running CI

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that our CI has no access to our AWS RDS instance, that's why the tests could not be ran on CI. Locally it did not work because the container was reaching the timeout for accessing the RDS, and if I tried `localhost` instead, it did not point to the host ip, since `localhost` inside the docker is the container itself, not the host.